# R: Problems with chron

Tags: r

I am a newbie to R, and I haven't been able to find any help on the following chron problem.

I am using R 2.6.2 and I am having problems with converting a character string to a chron or date object.

I want the string "20110810" for 10th of August 2011 to be converted to a date via chron.

Here is my code:

```
library(chron)
chron("20110810", format = "ymd")
chron(dates = "20110810", format = "ymd")
```

- and I get 201108, no matter what.

It seems like only a two digits year is recognized. How do I get chron to accept a four digit year as input?

I prefer to use chron as I also have a time vector of added times, which works just fine with chron.

Comment: R-2.6.2 really?  That version is 3.5 years old.  You should really upgrade...

Answer (score 2):

Using `as.Date`:

```
as.Date("20110810", format="%Y%m%d")
[1] "2011-08-10"
```

And using `chron` on R version 2.13.1:

```
chron("20110810", format="ymd")
[1] 110810
```

Your issue may be simply due to the fact that you are using a very old version of R.